# How do interpret statistically NULL SVM Output

Tags: svm, predictive-models, libsvm

I am using LibSVM (3.18) as an implementation of SVM. But every time when I'm predicting the result, it's giving zero.

I am following these instructions:

- I have CSV file (+50K lines), Most of data in column (target) is zeros, the other values are between 1-10.
- I convert csv file to libsvm data by selecting this column as label.
- When I Scale Data, I use these parameters

  $ svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 data.cv>scaled.data
- As I have a huge file, I use Subset.py.
- When I finish all the steps and apply predict. I got good result of accuracy.

  $svm-predict scaled_data.csv model.train data.predicted

  Accuracy = 94.28%

but the file I get (data.predicted) contains only zeros.

What does this mean statistically ?

Is it tricky to predict this kind of data ? Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Assuming the positive label is `+1` you should do `svm-train -w+1 100 -c 0.03125 -g 0.0078125 -v 5 -q`. Note that you might need to optimize `c` again.

Comment: Perfect! One more thing, by mentioning -c, i run grid.py on small data that extracted using subset. how accurate is subset in this case ? I mean, if we get small data, we might find only zeros in this data as we have a lot of negative points

Comment: If you have no instances of the positive class in a subset you cannot learn anything. libsvm will complain when this happens.

Comment: grid.py is taking a long time (+24 hours) when i apply on the whole file, that's why I used subset to accelerate the process

Answer (score 2):

You probably have very few positives compared to negatives. This is called an imbalanced setting. In this case, predicting everything as negative will yield high accuracy even though it is useless.

If you indeed have an imbalanced data set, you can improve your models by assigning a higher misclassification to positive instances during training. In libsvm you can do this using the `-w` flag.

A good heuristic to assign class weights is to use the following equation:
$$C_{pos} \times n_{pos} = C_{neg} \times n_{neg}.$$
Ex.: if you have 1 positive and 100 negatives, $C_{pos}$ should be $100 C_{neg}$.

Comment: Thanks ! That's very very useful. at which step should I do this ? (I mean: when I scale, predict or cross-validate data ..)

Comment: You can assign misclassification penalties per class while training models using `svm-train`.

Comment: "I don't lack data, but the phenomena I am doing a study about is rare", I am doing statistics now about the data I have; 98% of the data is zero. Is it accurate to use the factor this way.

Comment: I couldn't found "-w" flag, but I found "-wi weight" : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)

Comment: @user3378649 that is the flag you need. Replace `i` by the label of the positive class.

Comment: Can you please check the update. Is this what you mentioned ?

Comment: I've worked on your approach, I got some results but it's not sufficient. (10-50 out of 20k). Should I augment the coefficient again. Or should I think about another approach to tackle this problem ?